# FreeBSD and Linux VLAN

Tags: linux, freebsd, ipv6, local-area-network, vlan

I have a LAN and i need to create a LAB with three VLAN on my boxes, Linux and FreeBSD.

Well i create a VLAN 1 on the linux box as follow:

```
sudo vconfig add eth0 1
sudo ifconfig eth0.1 inet6 add 2001:470:9b36:2::2/64
```

and i do the same on the FreeBSD box:

```
sudo ifconfig vlan1 create
sudo ifconfig vlan1 inet6 2001:470:9b36:2::1 prefixlen 64 vlan 1 vlandev bge0
```

ifconfig of FreeBSD box

```
vlan2: flags=8843 metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=3
    ether 00:11:85:61:90:f2
    inet6 fe80::211:85ff:fe61:90f2%vlan2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    inet6 2001:470:9b36:2::1 prefixlen 64 
    inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    nd6 options=3
    media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX )
    status: active
    vlan: 2 parent interface: bge0
```

and the ifconfig of the Linux Box:

```
eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:d3:85:28:d3:28

          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dad3:85ff:fe28:d328/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:9b36:2::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:962 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:43400 (42.3 KiB)
```

But i still not able to ping the VLANs from each side ?
What would be the states of each of the interfaces bge0 and eth0 ?

NB: the eth0 and bge0 are up and running

Comment: Is vlan1 on FreeBSD up?

Comment: the two vlans are up and running

Comment: Can both ends ping their own VLAN ip? Next I'd see if the traffic shows on the other end with tcpdump -evni bge0 / eth0

Comment: In the both side i see  "neighbor solicitation, who has" request

Comment: Is the whohas request answerred? Does `ndp -a` on FreeBSD or `ip neigh show` on Linux show the other end's MAC?

Comment: Is bge0 configured on the FreeBSD box? If not, by default it will be disabled, a quick `ifconfig bge0 up` will enable it. Are they connected by a managed switch? If it's vlan aware it might only allow certain vlans on each interface, and would need to be configured to allow the new vlans.

Comment: bge0 is configured and has an address, and i can ping this address from Linux box, the same for eth0, and about the switch it is a mini switch 5 ports level 2, that interconnect the two boxes.

Comment: Are the base interfaces using IPv6 and working correctly? You don't have firewall rules or something similar not allowing IPv6 through? The configuration seems correct (straight forward), it's likely something silly/simple.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something other then VLAN1?  VLAN1 is typically considered to be the un-tagged VLAN.  Generally you should not be trying to add that as a tagged VLAN.

I am not sure about FreeBSD, but in Linux, there is a warning when you try to use that.

How are the two systems physically connected?

Comment: they are connected using an Ethernet switch Netgear, i think that even i use other VLAN the problem still there

Comment: Is it a managed switched or unmanaged? Which model?

Comment: an unmanaged netgear ethernet switch

Answer (score 0):

If all you see is the 'who has' requests, there is no ethernet traffic on the chosen vlan. A switch with vlan or jumbo frame support may be needed, although I'm not sure about this (neighbour discovery and icmp6 traffic shouldn't use 1500 byte frames).

Could you post the output of 'ifconfig -a' on both systems? My guess is something is missing.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need a Layer 2  switch that will support 802.1Q. Effectively, that would mean a managed switch. On an unmanaged switch, there is no mechanism for the frame to be routed based on the tag.

Comment: -1 No, a switch that is not 802.1q aware will simply pass the packet along without consideration for the vlan tag.

Comment: Fair enough. I probably need to review how VLAN should work, then.